# Как сократить скрипт

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

Получился какой то невалидный и большой код... подскажите пожалуйста знатоки как его можно сократить ?

```
<script>
$('#item-cards > div #select-clinic').on('change', function() {
    var $doctor_id = $('option:selected', this).attr('data-doctor-id');
    var $clinic_id = $('option:selected', this).attr('data-clinic-id');
    var $select_item = '#item-cards > #item-' + $doctor_id + '';

    $.ajax({
        url: '/index.php?route=doctor/doctor/clinic_selected',
        type: 'post',
        data: {
            doctor_id: $doctor_id,
            clinic_id: $clinic_id
        },
        dataType: 'json',
        beforeSend: function() {
            // add disable and spinner to button
            html = '<span class="spinner-grow spinner-grow-sm"></span> ';
            $(''+ $select_item +' .btn-order-clinic').prop( "disabled", true );
        },      
        success: function(json) {

            html = '<a class="text-dark" href="'+ json['href'] + '">' + json['clinic_name'] + '</a>';
            html += '<small class="d-block text-muted">ул. Гагарина 17, 33 оф.1 ' + json['clinic_name'] + '</small>';

            $(''+ $select_item +' .btn-order-clinic').attr("onclick","order_doctor('" + $doctor_id + "', '" + $clinic_id + "', '')");
            $(''+ $select_item +' .clinic-doctor-price').children().text(json['clinic_id']);
            $(''+ $select_item +' .clinic-info').html(html);

            $(''+ $select_item +' .btn-order-clinic').prop( "disabled", false );        

        },
        error: function(xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
            alert(thrownError + "\r\n" + xhr.statusText + "\r\n" + xhr.responseText);
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: В чём заключается его негодность? Где-то ошибки? В методе "beforeSend" для чего устанавливается переменная "html"?

Comment: Используйте так называемые "обфускаторы".

Answer (score 0):

Можно использовать создание строки с помощью Шаблонных литералов, тогда мы избавимся от лишних плюсов, например:

```
html = `<a class='text-dark' href='${json.href}'>${json.clinic_name}</a>
<small class='d-block text-muted'>ул. Гагарина 17, 33 оф.1 ${json.clinic_name}</small>`;
```